# Numerical optimization

Tags: numerical-methods

Suppose that I need to find the global maximum of $f(x)$ but $f'(x)=0$ and $f''(x)=0$ can only be solved numerically. How do I am 100% sure that I have found the correct optimums. My doubt is because the algorithms do not find the roots with probability one.

Comment: Do you have some specific function in mind?

Comment: Yes, this one. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/294712/unique-root-by-numerical-solution and that root is a maximum.